# MySQL result redirection / linked rows?

Tags: mysql, database, search, redirect, rows

I have an inventory database. Some of the products can only be purchased in a multipack. I want my customers to be able to perform a product search on the individual items, returning their corresponding multipack if matches are found.

```
Table     | ID | Length | Height | Parent |
----------+----+--------+--------+--------+
Product1  | 1  | 100    | 500    | 3      | - Don't return this
Product2  | 2  | 200    | 50     | 3      | - Don't return this
Multipack | 3  | 200    | 500    | NULL   | + Return this
```

If the customer searches for products with length <150, The multipack should be returned because product 1 matches this criterion.
If the customer searches for products with length <600, The multipack should be returned only once, even though all three entries match this criterion. Is there a way to tell MySQL that Product1 and Product2 should be returned as Multipack for query results? What's the best way to handle this? The database has about 20,000 rows and 200 multipacks. Thanks - skibulk

Comment: How do you know that the Multipack is related to Product1 and Product2?

Comment: Where does it say that the multipack contains product 1

Comment: updated the table with "Parent" column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some food for thought...

How about a subquery in the WHERE clause that returns a distinct list of non multpack ids matching your criteria. Then `AND` a NULL condition so you only select the multipack.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table,Length,Height FROM Inventory WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inventory WHERE length < x and Parent => 0) AND Parent = NULL
```